# The difference between an any type and a generic type in swift

Tags: swift, generics, types

What is the difference between an any type and generic type in swift?

Any Type Example:

```
let swiftInt: Int = 1
let swiftString: String = "miao"

var array: [Any] = []
array.append(swiftInt)
array.append(swiftString)
```

Generic Type Example:

```
func duplicate<T>(item: T, numberOfTimes n: Int) -> [T] {
  var buffer : [T] = []
  for _ in 0 ..< n {
    buffer.append(item)
  }
  return buffer
}
```

Is this a matter of preference because both appear to solve the same problem by being able to substitute the desired type.

Comment: Shortly: First array can contain `String` **and** `Int`. Second array can contain `String` **or** `Int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to explain generics in details and i'll just point out the essential differences.

In the first example, you'll be able to append any type in that array, without being able to restrict beforehand your array to a specific type and to leverage **compile time checks** to guarantee that the array will not contain extraneous types. Not much to see in that example.

The second example contains instead a generic function that provides all of the above functionalities, consistency checks on the content of the array will come for free and if you want you'll also be able to specify additional characteristics of that generic type `T`, like requesting that it implements a specific protocol (e.g. limit `duplicate()` to object that implement `Comparable` or `Equatable`).

But that is just a simple example of a generic function, you can also have parametrized classes (what you'll use the most) and there are a lot of additional functionalities.

Never use `Any` as a poor-man generics, real generics are way more flexible, add useful checks and make more explicit your intentions, with  minimal additional effort required to implement them.

Answer (score 2):

`Any` means "I don't want any type checking and I won't be able to call type-specific methods without casting"

For example, try to call:

```
var array: [Any] = [1, 2]
var sum = array[0] + array[1] // you cannot do this! you have to cast to Int first
```

A generic type is a placeholder for a type. When used, a concrete type is used instead of it (e.g. an `Int` or a `String`).

In short, never use `Any`. There are very very few specific situations when `Any` is what you want to use.

Comment: When you say "a concrete type" @Sulthan are you referring to only ints, strings, doubles, arrays, etc. and not custom types  such as those created from custom classes?  It sounds like a Generic is more so for if you don't know what the type will be before hand while programming, is that an accurate statement?

Comment: The concrete type is the type you choose to use when you'll use a generic (also called parametric) function/class. It can be anything, one of your custom classes/structs too.